# Force psqlODBC Postgres drivers to use Windows Trusted Root Certificate Store

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I need to configure my client software to use SSL when connecting to a postgres database (`sslmode=verify-full`). The configuration requires me to specify a root certificate file in the following directory: `c:\users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\root.crt.` The file path may change depending on what user is running the program, and in any case I can use `sslrootcert` setting to specify some common path. However, the software that I'm working on is already using Windows Certificate Store to check certificates and I'd like to force postgres drivers to use it, instead of a file. Is it possible somehow to configure psqlODBC drivers to use Windows Certificate Store to verify server cert?

Comment: Apparently, psqlODBC does not directly support CAPI. Try stunnel.

Comment: @CL Thanks, I'll take a look. Too bad there is no way to configure it out of the box. I was expecting something similar to sslfactory in postgres jdbc drivers that can override the default behavior.